# find median element index c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, median

I have some points like (g1, g2). I want to find median point by following formula:

[image: median1]

a naive solution is to use a nested loop but it's so inefficient for a large space (about 1 million points).
does anyone know a linear time algorithm/code or near linear time for doing this in c++?

I implement the naive solution as following but it does not efficient for my problem:

```
vector<double> get_dists(unordered_map<string, label*> myGraph) {
    vector<double> sum_dists;
    for (unordered_map<string, label*>::iterator it = myGraph.begin(); it != myGraph.end(); it++) {
        double d = 0;
        for (unordered_map<string, label*>::iterator it2 = myGraph.begin(); it2 != myGraph.end(); it2++)
        {
            d += dist(it->second->num, it2->second->num)
        }
        sum_dists.push_back(d);
    }
    return sum_dists;
}
```

it return a vector of sum of distances and the it can use to get minimum element index.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Pass collection by const reference instead of by value to avoid copies.

Comment: I just updated the dist() function. can you explain more about pass by const in my code? Thank you @Jarod42

Comment: Well, doing some back of the envelope calculations, finding the median coordinates should be `O(n)`. Once this is found, then finding the point nearest the median point should also be `O(n)`, for the final complexity of `O(n)`?

Comment: I meant `get_dists(const std::unordered_map<std::string, label*>& myGraph)`

Comment: Why does it say "median element index" in the title but your function is called "get dists"? In any case, is your question about C++ or the algorithm (which is language-agnostic)?

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42. it was very good hint but it does not solve my time efficiency problem about that.

Comment: Isn't sorting element (by axis) allow to find median (or at least candidates).